Databricks querying PostgressSql - timestamp as string including timezone
I am doing ETL in Databricks which takes data from Postgres database.
When I directly query Postgres for delivery_from, I get "2024-07-01 00:00:00+02" which is the desired result.
When I was storing data in Databricks stored as "2024-06-30T22:00:00.000".
Which isn't desirable since it throws away original timezone information.
I can query the source database but I can't create any objects.
When I query the postgresql directly delivery_from::text I get "2024-07-01 00:00:00+02".
I reasoned that if I were to run query from databricks which converts to string I would get the same result but I get "2024-06-30 22:00:00".
I managed to replicate the desired outcome with a hardcode for this timezone is used CONCAT(date_format(CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', 'Europe/Paris', delivery_from), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), '+02').

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Looks like DataBricks is storing the timestamp at UTC, if I am following this, Timestamp: Timestamps with local timezone are internally normalized and persisted in UTC., correctly. In that case you have fixed point in time which you can convert to any other with appropriate time zone conversion.
